# Recursion - Node out of memory

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion, express, v8

When I run the following code 9999999+ times, Node returns with:

```
FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_2 Allocation failed - process out of memory
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Whats the best solution to get around this issue, other than increasing the max alloc size or any command line arguments?

I'd like to improve the code quality rather than hack a solution.

The following is the main bulk of recursion within the application.

The application is a load testing tool.

```
a.prototype.createClients = function(){
    for(var i = 0; i < 999999999; i++){
        this.recursiveRequest();
    }
}

a.prototype.recursiveRequest = function(){
    var self    =   this;
    self.hrtime =   process.hrtime();

    if(!this.halt){
        self.reqMade++;

        this.http.get(this.options, function(resp){
            resp.on('data', function(){})
                .on("connection", function(){
                })
                .on("end", function(){
                    self.onSuccess();
                });
        })
            .on("error", function(e){
                self.onError();
            });
    }
}

a.prototype.onSuccess = function(){
    var elapsed     =   process.hrtime(this.hrtime),
        ms          =   elapsed[0] * 1000000 + elapsed[1] / 1000

        this.times.push(ms);
        this.successful++;
        this.recursiveRequest();
}
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve with this code?

Comment: It's a load testing application.

Comment: use multi-mechanize instead http://testutils.org/multi-mechanize/

Comment: That doesn't answer my question, I'm rolling my own load testing suite, because hey, it's fun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you should really be using a queue instead of recursive calls.  `async.queue` offers a fantastic mechanism for processing asynchronous queues.  You should also consider using the `request` module to make your http client connections simpler.

```
var async = require('async');
var request = require('request');

var load_test_url = 'http://www.testdomain.com/';
var parallel_requests = 1000;

function requestOne(task, callback) {
  request.get(task.url, function(err, connection, body) {
    if(err) return callback(err);
    q.push({url:load_test_url});
    callback();
  });
}

var q = async.queue(requestOne, parallel_requests);

for(var i = 0; i < parallel_requests; i++){
  q.push({url:load_test_url});
}
```

You can set the `parallel_requests` variable according to how many simultaneous requests you want to hit the test server with.

Comment: I think the `for` loop will still lead to the out-of-memory error, given the number of iterations performed...

Comment: `async.queue` is not recursive.  Memory is freed between requests.

Comment: @Daniel, yeah, but the OP has 10 million in his for loop, not 1,000... That means 10 million calls to requestOne() before releasing anything.

Comment: OP was just trying to create a continuos load for load testing if you read the comments below the post.  OP doesn't really need 10 million concurrent requests to accomplish the goal.

Answer (score 1):

You are launching 1 billion "clients" in parallel, and having each of them perform an http get request recursively in an endless recursion.

Few remarks:

- while your question mentions 10 million clients, your code creates 1 billion clients.
- You should replace the `for` loop by a recursive function, to get rid of the out-of-memory error.

Something in these lines:

```
a.prototype.createClients = function(i){
    if (i < 999999999) {
        this.recursiveRequest();
        this.createClients(i+1);
    }
}
```

- Then, you probably want to include some delay between the clients creations, or between the calls to `recursiveRequest`. Use `setTimeout`.
- You should have a way to get the recursions stopping (`onSuccess` and `recursiveRequest` keep calling each other)
- A flow control library like [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) node.js module may help.

Comment: I agree, I feel this and the above post will be the solutions to my issue, I will follow this up with an answer when done.

Answer (score 0):

10 million is very large... Assuming that the stack supports any number of calls, it *should* work, but you are likely asking the JavaScript interpreter to load 10 million x quite a bit of memory... and the result is Out of Memory.

Also I personally do no see why you'd want to have so many requests at the same time (testing a heavy load on a server?) one way to optimize is to NOT create "floating functions" which you are doing a lot. "Floating functions" use their own set of memory on each instantiation.

```
this.http.get(this.options, function(resp){ ... });
                            ^^^^
                            ++++--- allocates memory x 10 million
```

Here the `function(resp)...` declaration allocates more memory on each call. What you want to do is:

```
# either global scope:
function r(resp) {...}
this.http.get(this.options, r ...);

# or as a static member:
a.r = function(resp) {...};
this.http.get(this.options, a.r ...);
```

At least you'll save on all that function memory. That goes for all the functions you declare within the *r* function, of course. Especially if their are quite large.

If you want to use the this pointer (make `r` a prototype function) then you can do that:

```
a.prototype.r = function(resp) {...};

// note that we have to have a small function to use 'that'... probably not a good idea
var that = this;
this.http.get(this.options, function(){that.r();});
```

To avoid the `that` reference, you may use an instance saved in a global. That defeats the use of an object as such though:

```
a.instance = new a;

// r() is static, but can access the object as follow:
a.r = function(resp) { a.instance.<func>(); }
```

Using the instance you can access the object's functions from the static `r` function. That could be the actual implementation which could make full use of the `this` reference:

```
a.r = function(resp) { a.instance.r_impl(); }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to a comment by Daniel, your problem is that you misuse a `for()` to count the total number of requests you want to send. This means you can apply a very simple fix to your code as follow:

```
a.prototype.createClients = function(){
    this.recursiveRequest();
};

a.prototype.recursiveRequest = function(){
    var self    =   this;
    self.hrtime =   process.hrtime();

    if(!this.halt && this.successful < 10000000){
...
```

Your recursivity is enough to run the test any number of times.

What you do is never quit, though. You have a `halt` variable, but it does not look like you ever set that to true. However, to test 10 million times, you want to check the number of requests you already sent.

My "fix" supposes that onError() fails (is no recursive). You could also change the code to make use of the halt flag as in:

```
a.prototype.onSuccess = function(){
    var elapsed     =   process.hrtime(this.hrtime),
        ms          =   elapsed[0] * 1000000 + elapsed[1] / 1000

        this.times.push(ms);
        this.successful++;
        if(this.successful >= 10000000)
        {
            this.halt = true;
        }
        this.recursiveRequest();
}
```

Note here that you will be pushing ms in the times buffer 10 million times. That's a big table! You may want to have a total instead and compute an average at the end:

```
   this.time += ms;

   // at the end:
   this.average_time = this.time / this.successful;
```